# OpenGL Texture Mapping Not mapping

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es

I am creating a flat surface and applying a texture for it. But for some reason the texture is not getting applied properly. I am getting something like this.

[image: This is what the output looks like]
This is the code that I am using (I have a class for applying textures),

```
for(int i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 512; j++) {
        int c = ((((i&0x8)==0)^(((j&0x8))==0)))*255;

        checkImage[i][j][0] = (GLubyte) c;
        checkImage[i][j][1] = (GLubyte) c;
        checkImage[i][j][2] = (GLubyte) c;
        checkImage[i][j][3] = (GLubyte)255;
        //cout<<"("<<(int)dataForPixel.rgbtRed<<","<<(int)dataForPixel.rgbtGreen<<","<<(int)dataForPixel.rgbtBlue<<")";
    }
}
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glGenTextures(1, &texName);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,       GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,       GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,   GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,   GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
             0,
             GL_RGBA,
             imageX,
             imageY,
             0,
             GL_RGBA,
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
             checkImage
);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2d(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3d(-100, -100,  0.0);
glTexCoord2d(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3d(-100,  100,  0.0);
glTexCoord2d(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3d( 100,  100,  0.0);
glTexCoord2d(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3d( 100, -100,  0.0);
glEnd();
```

The image is a 512 x 512 image.

Why is the texture not applying properly.

UPDATE:
The c value is just for producing a chess board pattern which consists of squares of 8 pixels width and height of alternating black and white.

Comment: Are you using a shader? If not, then how are you drawing without glBegin and glEnd?

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of `checkImage`? Is it `GLubyte` or an equivalent type? Also I don't think `c` in that top loop ends up being what you intend — it'll be either 0 or 2040. But should truncate to 248 anyway, which is close enough.

Comment: Yes check image is an array of GLubyte type. Also I have added an explanation of the c in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out the problem. Seems i was trying to allocate the checkImage memory dynamically but not in one go. So there were gaps in the memory which the OpenGL did not bother with.

Once I fixed it to allocate the memory as one big chunk it worked.